# EF-core howto set up many2many relationship to 'itself'

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-2.0

Case : Teammember is anyone who is working at a hospital. Teammembers (doctors) can have other teammembers as their assistants (nurse or another doctor), or teammembers can be an assistant of another teammember.

Classes

```
public class Teammember 
{
    Public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<AssistantLink> AssistantLinks { get; } = new List<AssistantLink>();
    public ICollection<Teammember> Assistants => AssistantLinks.Where(x => x.CareProviderId == Id).Select(x => x.Assistant).ToList();
    public ICollection<Teammember> CareProviders => AssistantLinks.Where(x => x.AssistantId == Id).Select(x => x.CareProvider).ToList();
}
```

To set up this relationship I created a class 'AssistantLink'

```
   public class AssistantLink : ModelBase
    {
        public int CareProviderId { get; set; }
        public Teammember CareProvider { get; set; }
        public int AssistantId { get; set; }
        public Teammember Assistant { get; set; }
    }
```

In the DB context I tried to wire up this relationship via:

```
    builder.Entity<AssistantLink>().HasKey(x => new { x.CareProviderId, x.AssistantId });
    builder.Entity<AssistantLink>().HasOne(x => x.CareProvider).WithMany("AssistantLinks"); //use string notation because navigation property is private
    builder.Entity<AssistantLink>().HasOne(x => x.Assistant).WithMany("AssistantLinks");
```

When creating a db-migration I get the following

> ERROR : Cannot create a relationship between
>   'Teammember.AssistantLinks' and 'AssistantLink.Assistant', because
>   there already is a relationship between 'Teammember.AssistantLinks'
>   and 'AssistantLink.CareProvider'. Navigation properties can only
>   participate in a single relationship.

Any suggestions how to set up this the correct way ?

Comment: EF Core doesn't support many to many, so you instead of have to have *two* one-to-many relationships, between an intermediary entity and each side of the relationship. Here, each side of the relationship just happens to be the same entity, so you need two collections on that entity, one for each side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have just one collection with relations. You need two - one with assistantlinks the teammember equals `CareProvider` and second with assistantlinks the teammember equals `Assistant`.

Model

```
public class Teammember
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AssistantLink> Assistants { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<AssistantLink> Providers { get; set; }
}
public class AssistantLink : ModelBase
{
    public int CareProviderId { get; set; }
    public Teammember CareProvider { get; set; }
    public int AssistantId { get; set; }
    public Teammember Assistant { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AssistantLink>()
            .HasKey(x => new { x.CareProviderId, x.AssistantId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<AssistantLink>()
            .HasOne(al => al.CareProvider)
            .WithMany(c => c.Providers)
            .HasForeignKey(al => al.CareProviderId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        modelBuilder.Entity<AssistantLink>()
            .HasOne(al => al.Assistant)
            .WithMany(a => a.Assistants)
            .HasForeignKey(al => al.AssistantId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); 
    }
```